# use flatlist instead scrollview

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I've the following code, it works fine I can connect to an API and fetch the data, since I'm getting a huge list of threads how can I refactor the code using Flatlist instead?

thanks

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import ThreadDetail from './ThreadDetail';

class TopicList extends Component {
  state = {
    threads: []
  };

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('https://xxxxxxx.devmn.net/api/v1/forums/threads?topic_id=2418', {
      headers: {
        'client-id': 'a0f21e'
      }
    })
      .then(response => this.setState({ threads: response.data.threads }));
  }

  renderThreads() {
    return this.state.threads.map(thread =>
      <ThreadDetail key={thread.thread.id} thread={thread.thread} />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.listStyle}>
        {this.renderThreads()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  listStyle: {
    backgroundColor: 'purple'
  }
}

export default TopicList;
```

Comment: Did your problem solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
export default class TopicList extends Component {

     constructor() {
           super(props);

           this.state = {
                threads: []
           }
     }

     componentWillMount() {
           .... // same as your code
     }

     renderItem({index, item}) {
           return <ThreadDetail thread={item.thread} />
     }

     render() {
          return <View>
                     <FlatList 
                         data={this.state.threads}
                         renderItems={this.renderItem}
                         keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.thread.id} />
                 </View>
     }
}
```

*note: I haven't tested this*

Comment: I get an error in the iOS simulator `Cannot read property 'index' of undefined, @BrainYoung

Comment: My code looks like this https://jsbin.com/jakojuhomo/edit?js when I ve the error with the `index` undefined. @Brain Young

Comment: @AlbertoFerioli Can you show me how your thread data is structured? `response.data.threads`

Comment: I ve attached a screenshot below @Brain Young. thanks